# how to add row in DataFrame iteratively updating it after each for loop in python preferably in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, reshape, concatenation

This is my .csv file

```
Choco_Type,ID,Cocoa,Milk,Sugar,ID,Cocoa,Milk,Sugar 
Dark,Batch_11,80,0,16,Batch_12,78,0,14 
Milk,Batch_72,35,25,25,Batch_73,32,27,22 
Swiss,Batch_52,30,30,20,Batch_53,28,33,18
```

This is my code

```
for row in reader_in:
    type_chocolate=row[0]
    a= [(type_chocolate,row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]),(type_chocolate,row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8])]
    df=DataFrame.from_records(a)
```

this should be my output DataFrame

```
Choco_Type   ID  Cocoa  Milk Sugar  
Dark    Batch_11    80  0   16  
Dark    Batch_12    78  0   14  
Milk    Batch_72    35  25  25  
Milk    Batch_73    32  27  22  
Swiss   Batch_52    30  30  20  
Swiss   Batch_53    28  33  18
```

I am unable to understand how to update the DataFrame'df' after each 'for' loop with new rows which are updated by using 'from_records' function which takes a list of iterables from the reader_in as it's input

Comment: Question, why are you loading a single line at a time? Why don't you just read the whole file in using `read_table` or `read_csv`?

Comment: I read the full csv file but I am modifying each line and further I wanted to create a DataFrame from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for creating `DataFrame` from `csv`.

Then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) `.1` to empty string what was added  for NO duplicates in columns names.

[`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with first column and use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) with selecting first and last `4` columns by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""Choco_Type,ID,Cocoa,Milk,Sugar,ID,Cocoa,Milk,Sugar
Dark,Batch_11,80,0,16,Batch_12,78,0,14
Milk,Batch_72,35,25,25,Batch_73,32,27,22
Swiss,Batch_52,30,30,20,Batch_53,28,33,18"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print (df)

  Choco_Type        ID  Cocoa  Milk  Sugar      ID.1  Cocoa.1  Milk.1  Sugar.1
0       Dark  Batch_11     80     0     16  Batch_12       78       0       14
1       Milk  Batch_72     35    25     25  Batch_73       32      27       22
2      Swiss  Batch_52     30    30     20  Batch_53       28      33       18


df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.1', '')
df = df.set_index('Choco_Type')
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :4], df.iloc[:, 4:]]).reset_index()

print (df)
  Choco_Type        ID  Cocoa  Milk  Sugar
0       Dark  Batch_11     80     0     16
1       Milk  Batch_72     35    25     25
2      Swiss  Batch_52     30    30     20
3       Dark  Batch_12     78     0     14
4       Milk  Batch_73     32    27     22
5      Swiss  Batch_53     28    33     18
```

If order is necessary changed by desired output:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace('.1', '')
df = df.set_index('Choco_Type')
df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:, :4], df.iloc[:, 4:]], keys=(1,2), axis=1)
       .stack(0)
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
       .reset_index()
print (df)

  Choco_Type        ID  Cocoa  Milk  Sugar
0       Dark  Batch_11     80     0     16
1       Dark  Batch_12     78     0     14
2       Milk  Batch_72     35    25     25
3       Milk  Batch_73     32    27     22
4      Swiss  Batch_52     30    30     20
5      Swiss  Batch_53     28    33     18
```

Another solution with `pd.lreshape` by `dict` which is created by `dict comprehension` with column names which not contains `.1`, also is necessery remove `Choco_Type`:

```
cols = df.columns[~((df.columns.str.contains('.1')) | (df.columns == 'Choco_Type'))]
print (cols)
Index(['ID', 'Cocoa', 'Milk', 'Sugar'], dtype='object')

d = {x: df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(x)].tolist() for x in cols}
print (d)
{'Milk': ['Milk', 'Milk.1'], 
'Sugar': ['Sugar', 'Sugar.1'], 
'ID': ['ID', 'ID.1'], 
'Cocoa': ['Cocoa', 'Cocoa.1']}

df = pd.lreshape(df, d)
print (df)
  Choco_Type  Milk  Sugar        ID  Cocoa
0       Dark     0     16  Batch_11     80
1       Milk    25     25  Batch_72     35
2      Swiss    30     20  Batch_52     30
3       Dark     0     14  Batch_12     78
4       Milk    27     22  Batch_73     32
5      Swiss    33     18  Batch_53     28
```

Comment: what does .1 mean in str.replace

Comment: it means column names are `ID.1` so you need remove `.1` (this problem is in pandas 0.19.2, in some older version pandas doesnt add `.1` if duplicates column names)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! but could you mind explaining me what is reset_index and how it is used here

Comment: Sure, you can check [indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html). I create index from first column `Choco_Type` for `Dataframe` with all data for reshape. After concat still `Choco_Type` is index, so I use `reset_index` for creating column from index.

Comment: i got NAN values for sugar when I used my filename.csv

Comment: are data confidental? If not, can you send me your csv to my email in my profile?

Comment: if I use StringIO(temp) it is returning correct output but if I use filename.csv it is giving NAN values for the sugar values.I also mailed you my screenshot

Comment: How to solve if there are multiple batches in a single row, should I set_index() for multiple columns and do a for loop to split the input into half multiple times

Comment: Yes. You can use `df = df.set_index(['Choco_Type', 'col1','col2'])`. But I am not sure what mean half of multiple times. Can you change question with this data  3-5 rows?